# Django validate the input as a valid foreign key

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

In django rest framework, have a POST api that creates a `City` object.
However it also receives a list of ids of `stadiums`.

What is the best way to validate each of the ids are valid `stadium_ids` (present and not deleted in the table `Stadiums`).

Comment: Share code. Are the ids stored inside model? Are you using serializer? What view do you use?

Comment: How are you passing the ids?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First put list of ids in a set to distinct probable repeated ids:

```
ids = set(ids)
```

Then filter stadiums based on this ids:

```
stadiums = Stadium.object.filter(id__in=ids)
```

If some stadiums are not present in database, then count of stadiums is less than size of ids:

```
if len(ids) != len(stadiums):
    # Handle Error
```

Comment: Also note, you can pass a list or array of ids in that filter statement filter(id__in=[1,2,])